# How to use a stored procedure for Entity Framework model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Hi before I use to retrieve and manipulate data directly from my DB..but this time I am using Entity Data Model.. I have all the tables in my `.edmx` file .... I have some queries in my DB for retrieving data but now as I am using Entity Data Model I don't know how to call that procedure in my controller as I am using MVC 3 here can any one tell me how to get the data using my stored procedure or write a Linq query similar to my stored procedure in my controller

Here is my stored procedure:

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[ProjectReports]
   (
    @ProjectID int,
    @ReleasePhaseID int
   )
   as
   begin
   select distinct projectName,ReleasePhase,
   (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and           
     ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='New')) as Newbugs,
     (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and    
     ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Assigned')) as  
     Assignedbugs,
     (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and  
     ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Fixed')) as Fixedbugs,
      (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and
       ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Re-Opened')) as 
Reopenedbugs,
    (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and 
     ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Closed')) as Closedbugs,
     (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and  
     ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
     bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Deffered')) as Defferedbugs,
     (Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and  
      ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
      bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Not a Bug')) as NotaBug
      from Bugs a
      inner join Projects p on p.ProjectId=a.ProjectId
      inner join ReleasePhase Rp on rp.ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID
      where a.ProjectId=@ProjectID and a.ReleasePhaseID=@ReleasePhaseID
     end
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is:

1. Open your .edmx model in VS designer
2. Right-click and select "Update Model From Database..." (stuff like that)
3. Choose your SP from the given dialog and hit "Finish"
4. In your Controller write:

   ```
    var result = new YourEntitiesName().StoredProcedureName();
   ```

Comment: It works without function import. I don't know the details though.